# Differential Forms and Relativistic Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, tensor-calculus

Let $\phi$ represent the electric potential and let $\textbf{A}$ represent the magnetic potential. Then, the electric field is given by

\begin{equation}
\textbf{E} = -\nabla \phi - \partial_t \textbf{A} \; \; (\textrm{i})
\end{equation}
The magnetic field is given by
\begin{equation}
\textbf{B} = \nabla × \textbf{A} \; \; \; (\textrm{ii})
\end{equation}

Now, we can define the contravariant electromagnetic four-potential $A^\mu = (\phi/c, \textbf{A})$. Taking the Minkowski metric signature to be (+, -, -, -), we have that the covariant electromagnetic four-potential is $A_\mu = (\phi/c, -\textbf{A})$.

With this, we can define the electromagnetic one-form $ \alpha = A_\mu dx^\mu$. We can also define the electromagnetic two-form $F$:

\begin{equation}
F = d\alpha = F'_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} \; \; \; (\textrm{iii})
\end{equation}

Here, each $F'_{\mu\nu}$ is some zero-form scalar function. 
My question is this. Should $F'_{\mu \nu} = F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, where each $F_{\mu \nu}$ is a component of the covariant electromagnetic two-tensor? If so, is equation (iii) a valid definition of $F_{\mu \nu}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Here, each $F’_{\mu\nu}$ is some zero-form scalar function.* That’s not true.

Comment: Also (iii) is missing a $1/2$ normalization. Please edit appropriately.

Comment: And using $dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}=dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu}-dx^{\nu}\otimes dx^{\mu}$, you should be able to show $\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}= F_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \otimes dx^{\nu}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic I figured that there should be a $\frac{1}{2!}$ in (iii) to account for repeated terms in the summation, though I was not sure.  So I should get that $F= d\alpha = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial A_\nu}{\partial x^\mu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu = (\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)  dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$

Comment: @ G. Smith What is wrong with the statement that each $F'_{\mu \nu}$ is some zero-form scalar function?

Comment: It is possible that G.Smith is using indexes in some way other than their Einstein sum... If you choose a basis of a space then tensor components *should* be smooth scalar fields afterwards, I think.

Comment: @CRDrost: you're wrong. To contract indices both indices need to be the same - and with one index up to and one index down, e.g.,  $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}$. Where as $\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ has two dissimilar indices both down and is the coefficient of a $2$ order tensor.

Comment: To answer the question "What is wrong with the statement that each $F'_{\mu \nu}$  is some zero-form scalar function?" First, you started with $1$-form $\alpha = A_\mu dx^\mu$ then took the exterior derivative of the $1$-form which yielded a $2$-form, $d\alpha =\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\mu A_\mu) dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$. Perhaps you should include the space-time dependence in the differential forms.

Comment: See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form" and scroll down to "The exterior derivative" section.

Comment: @CinaedSimson suppose we define a coordinate map that has scalar fields $w,x,y,z$ over some open neighborhood of some point, it can be locally a Minkowski metric if that helps. On that neighborhood is there not then a scalar field $d\alpha(w, x)$ which is indeed equal to the $wx$-component of $d\alpha$ in these coordinates? They will not simultaneously transform to other coordinates, that scalar field is not the $wx$-component of that 2-form in other coordinates, but that is more than the little claim that was being made by OP.

Comment: @CRDrost: the solution has to be Minkowski space, it must be in the tangent plane,  and it must be at the point in question. In other words, at $T(M)_{p}$. And d is the $\mathbf{exterior \;derivative}$ - it maps a $0$-form to a $1$-form, a $1$-form to a $2$-form, etc. There were no stated restrictions on the coordinates where $\mu,\nu=0,1,2,3$. And if there were restrictions, they would enforced after the general solution was obtained.

Comment: I think you are still not understanding the claim OP made. The claim is precisely that if I have a 2-form which looks like $\alpha~dw\wedge dx + \beta~ dx\wedge dy+\dots$ the terms $\alpha,\beta,\dots$ are 0-forms (they have to be!) even if I write them for my own sanity’s sake as $\alpha=Q_{wx}, \beta=Q_{xy},\dots.$ The resulting composition is of course a 2-form and nobody is trying to claim the contrary. However there is an implicit claim that OP is chasing which is, “any $n$-form can be decomposed into a sum of scalars times the basis $n$-forms in my coordinates,” which is true.